# TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined doesnt work properly

Tags: javascript

So this code work with

```
try {
        const arrTemp = [];
        let resp = await axios.get(api_base_url);
        resp.data.data.forEach(element => {
            arrTemp.push(element);
        });
        while (resp.data.paging.hasOwnProperty('next')) {
            resp = await axios.get(resp.data.paging.next)
            resp.data.data.forEach(element => {
                arrTemp.push(element);
            })
        };
```

but i got an error from eslint by
no-prototype-builtins, on this code `while (resp.data.paging.hasOwnProperty('next'))`
so i tried to fix based on documentation:
while (Object.prototype.resp.data.paging.hasOwnProperty.call('next'))
but i got error
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

Comment: Try `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(resp.data.paging,'next'))`

Comment: thanks u so much Abdul Haseeb